# Can I merge two different wordpress themes and use it as one website?

Tags: php, wordpress

**Problem**

We are planning to create a small community directory website with our community business listings, events and some useful articles. No single WordPress theme is offering all 3 features in one theme.

**Thoughtful Solution**

We thought to buy one theme for listing, one for events and one for articles and somehow make one website.

**Question**

**Is it possible to combine / merge more then 2 WordPress themes and make change look so it feels like one single website and users can still access all the features and functions seamlessly?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes possible to combine two or three theme in wordpress but required too much afford and time. Here is something you can do:

1) Buy a theme that covers max of you concept and use some premium plugins.

2) Wordpress offer multisite where you can create multi site website under one installation and use different themes.to know more about multisite
[Click Here](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/)

3) Create sub folder in main installation like
  www.xyz.com 
  www.xyz.com/event
  www.xyz.com/articles

and install different wordpress use different theme to satisfy your needs

Comment: Thanks, If I create multisite or Subfolder.. will affect website performance ?

Answer (score 1):

**Yes**, It's possible but it will cost you a lot of time and effort. I recommend you to offer a freelancing job for an expert to do this for you, so the budget for the 3 themes will go for someone who can merge them all.

**Note:** I'm not sure if `Wordpress` doesn't have themes/plugins for these features.

Answer (score 0):

you can use plugins like "Multiple Themes" for this purpose.